# Can I set a UILabel to expand to fit an arbitrary amount of text?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uilabel

This question is more for development purposes and would never be used for a shipping app. I need to do a quick and dirty UILabel whose text field I can point to a really, really, long string. Really long. I've ben futzing in IB and can't figure out the correct magic handshake to allow a UILabel to balloon to a really large size. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a method in the [UIKit additions to NSString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to achieve this. You can get the size using [this method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:):

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
           minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize
        actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize
              forWidth:(CGFloat)width
         lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

Set the size of the label to the return value of this method and you're all set.

**EDIT:** That method is for one-line strings. If your string is more than one line, use [this method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString%5FUIKit%5FAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:):

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
     constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size
         lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much Jeff.

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: Whoops, forgot. Done. Cheers.